# Why does removing "http" from a link fix it's color?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following script:

```css
a:link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="www.honda.com">Go to Honda's official wesite </a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.honda.com">Go to Honda's official wesite once again</a></p>
```

The anchor element whose address doesn't start with `http://` doesn't open and gives 404 error. When I open the script with notepad++ and clicks on the first link I get redirected to `file:///C:/Users/user31782/Desktop/www.honda.com`

- Why doesn't the anchor element, whose address doesn't start with `http://`, get redirected to `www.honda.com` and change to purple(as being visited) ?

Comment: What browser are you using? It turns red in chrome for me...

Comment: I have found links are blue, turn red when clicked, and go purple when visited.  All of these can be overridden using CSS pseudo-attributes, for example for monochrome displays, or for users with various types of colour-blindness.

Comment: @MikeResoli I am using google chrome.

Comment: They are both red for me. I think your question is invalid...

Answer (score 4):

They are both red when you first see them. After you click on one of the and come back that one becomes blue since it's marked as visited.

If you want it to still be red then you need to add this to the css rules:

```
a:visited { 
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: No. Only the first link is red and it remains red even after the link is visited.

Comment: Then there got to be other css rules that impact the links. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using google chrome. Also the first link gives 404 error to me.

Comment: You are actually right. The problem is something else. Both links are initially red(SO was in my user agent's cache). The problem is that the first link actually doesn't get redirected to www.honda.com

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  you need to color the visited links:

```
a:visited { 
    color: red;
}
```

Long answer: links have four states (unvisited, visited, hover and active).  There are four pseudo selectors that enable you to style the state of the links:

```
a:link {
    color: red;
}
a:visited {
    color: red;
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
a:active {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your edit changed my question so I rolled it back. I know about these pseudo classes. But my question is different. I am asking why doesn't the second link in my question become red.

Comment: Actually the first link gives 404 error in my browser.